# How to generate query with multiple or condtions in sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I want to query with multiple or conditions in sequelize. Out of two, I have defined only one is reflected in the query generated using sequelize

Current Output:

```
SELECT `id`, `from_id`, `to_id`, `message`, `format`, `from_type`, `to_type`, `from_deleted_id`, `to_deleted_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at` FROM `messages` AS `Message` WHERE ((`Message`.`from_id` = '1' AND `Message`.`from_type` = 'user') OR
(`Message`.`from_id` = '3' AND `Message`.`from_type` = 'user'))
```

Expected Output:

```
SELECT `id`, `from_id`, `to_id`, `message`, `format`, `from_type`, `to_type`, `from_deleted_id`, `to_deleted_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at` FROM `messages` AS `Message` WHERE ((`Message`.`from_id` = '1' AND `Message`.`from_type` = 'user') OR
(`Message`.`from_id` = '3' AND `Message`.`from_type` = 'user')) AND  ((`Message`.`to_id` = '1' AND `Message`.`to_type` = 'user') OR
(`Message`.`to_id` = '3' AND `Message`.`to_type` = 'user'))
```

where object -

```
where_condition={
        [Op.or]: [
            {from_id: from_id,from_type:from_type},
            {from_id: to_id,from_type:to_type},
        ],
         [Op.or]: [
           {to_id: from_id,to_type:from_type},
           {to_id: to_id,to_type:to_type},
         ],

    }
```

Sequlize statement -

```
models.Message.findAll({where:where_condition})
```

Answer (score 0):

Where object for having multiple or conditions must be as follow -

```
where_condition={
  [Op.or]: [
        {
          [Op.and]: [
            {
              [Op.and]: [{ from_id: from_id }, { from_type: from_type }]
            },
            {
              [Op.and]: [{ from_id: to_id }, { from_type: to_type }]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          [Op.and]: [
            {
              [Op.and]: [{ to_id: from_id }, { to_type: from_type }]
            },
            {
              [Op.and]: [{ to_id: to_id }, { to_type: to_type }]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: @JapeshThakur, I have updated my answer, please verify now.